# Enabling GAE PHP runtime to allow local infile bulk insertion to Cloud SQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, pdo, google-cloud-sql

I came across [this article](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/) yesterday while researching how to boost insertion performance on Cloud SQL. This lead to finding out that that GAE for PHP supports [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#supportmysqlfeatures), however after much trial and error, I have yet to correctly implement it in my current project.

I have tried PDO and MySQLi queries individually with options to enabled for allow_local_infile and have also edited php.ini as such

```
[GAE Runtime Module]
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "phpversion, phpinfo, gc_enabled"

[mysql]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On

[mysqli]
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
```

When calling phpinfo() after a configured and successful connection to Cloud SQL;

```
Directive                   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    Off         Off
mysqli.allow_local_infile   Off         Off
```

Which leads to this PHP Fatal error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version'
```

So now I'm stuck wondering how one might go about getting the php.ini file to change these 2 settings appropriately on GAE for PHP. My Google-fu has mostly been yielding non-GAE scenarios, so reinstalling MySQL isn't exactly an option. Currently I'm just testing a simple local .txt file and a table with only 2 columns for 'id' and 'testcol'. Any advice or GAE specific examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine PHP has allow_local_infile set to [0](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/), and you cannot change it from your apps php.ini file as it is [PHP_INI_SYSTEM](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php).

Hence this feature is not available using App Engine PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stuart. I was thinking this as well until I read that you can [override PHP_INI_SYSTEM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini#About_php_ini).   
There are also [permanently disabled functions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Disabled_functions) that might I think are related to restricting changes to allow_local_infile.   
Since App Engine PHP is in beta, I try not to take the documentation as gospel, but it would be nice to also view a list core directives that conflict with with the aforementioned functions.